# PV(Photovoltaic) module characteristics from physics to Java

Tags: java, math, physics

I am working on simulation app of `PV(Photovoltaic)` module characteristic diagram.
Need an assistance, because i do not understand electricity well to adapt formulas to Java code.

```
I = f(V) function (I-V characteristic)
```

and

```
P = f(V) (P-V characteristic)
```

are the functions i need to implement.

[image]

I will be happy to any help or even an ideas! 
Spent 2 days, and than more i read - than less i understand.

[Link to the publication](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272420848_A_comparative_study_on_converter_topologies_for_maximum_power_point_tracking_application_in_photovoltaic_generation)

Comment: Implementing a function solely based on a bunch of diagrams doesn't make much sense. The actual mathematical expressions upon which the diagrams are based would get you a lot further. Take the functions you want to calculate and plug in the constants as specified in the paper as a first step.

Comment: We would be eager to provide assistance, if you asked a specific question. Notice that one of the V-I and V-P diagram is superfluous, as P= I.V.

Comment: Thank you for fixes, Paul and this is the difficultness - i cant figure out how to use it.

Comment: You need swt/swing modules that support graphs, mathematical formulas that fit those curves to start with.

Comment: Link to publication is broken. directs to : http://a_comparative_study_on_converter_topologies_for_maximum_power_point_tracking_application_in_photovoltaic_generation/

Comment: @dkb fixed the broken link. My bad

Comment: You have to dig in the paper or contact the authors to get the formulas that were plotted above. Reconstructing the formula from the plot is just wasting your time and also not a good use of Java (MatLab? or even Excel?). Once you have the formulas, ask another question if you still have difficulties coding them in Java.

Comment: Links to non-public documents are a very poor idea.

Comment: Forget about the lovely graphs for a while.  Concentrate on getting the formulas and the numbers right first.  You can always plot them in something familiar like Excel or another graphing program.  You don't want to get wrapped around the axle with Swing or generating plots.

Comment: @duffymo yes, true, and the problem is i do not understand the formulas well .. missing about 10% of meaning of formulas, and because of that i am keeping and keepping reading and re-reading, i am not stupid, so i have to understand it somewhen :) i hope sooner than later

Comment: Concentrate on the formulas.  If you can generate (x, y) pairs you're almost there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do with a purely empirical approach you can:

- use a simple model for the current curve, such as `I(V) = I0 - exp(a + b V)`, which is qualitatively similar.
- for a given curve, read the value of `I0` directly on the left axis. Then `log(I0 - I(V))` is a linear function and it is an easy matter to determine `a` and `b` from two points (you can use a linear regression, but this would be overkill).

Now you can plot the coefficients `I0`, `a`, `b` of the various curves as functions of the insolation or the temperature, and find an empirical model. On the insulation curves, I have the feeling that only `I0` varies, while on the temperature ones, only `a` does.

This would lead to a model of the form

```
I(V, J, t°) = I0(J) - exp(a(t°) + b V)
```

where `J` denotes the insulation.

Obviously,

```
P(V, J, t°) = I(V, J, t°) V
```

A simulation:

[image]

[image]

---

**Last minute:**

Looking at the plots of `I0(J)` and `b(t°)`, these models are clearly linear. Hence

```
I(V, J, t°) = (Ia + Ib J) - exp((Aa + Ab t°) + B V)
```

Comment: Looking at the aspect of the curves, I wouldn't be surprised that the exponential model was indeed used by the authors as an empirical estimate.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I am not able to think for now, its 10pm, and brain stopped working, but tomorrow i will check this out, and will thank you you again!!!

Comment: hello, sir, maybe you can assist me with finding the Isc (short-circuit current) and Voc (open-circuit voltage)?

Comment: @AlexeiE.: set $V=0$ or $I=0$.

Comment: i've found Isc-Vsc and Im and Vm is determined only by PV panel manufacturer :)

Comment: can you share the code of the simulation above? How does this looks like?